# How can I disassemble / repair a CPL (Circular Polarizing Filter)?

Tags: filters, repair

One of my circular (rotating) polarizing filters has a big hair between the two lenses. The hair moves around and I always have to shake it aside until it's out of sight.

[image]

<sub>*Similar to this*</sub>

How would I go about disassembling it and reassembling it (after I get rid of the tiny annoying hair)? I haven't been able to find any help/tutorial online and I'm not sure how the parts are welded together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know that this necessarily applies to *your* CPL, because it probably varies quite a bit by brand, model, etc.

However, on at least one brand CPL and GND filter I have, inside the front ring, using the same threads you'd use to stack a second filter, there is a very slim retaining ring that unscrews out the front, letting the glass fall out once it's out. There may be a similar arrangement on the rear. Having never fully disassembled one, though, I'm not sure how to separate the front half from the back half. But, if you can get one glass surface out, you should be able to clean the hair out. Just be sure you pay attention to which surface of the glass pointed which direction.

It's quite possible, though, especially on cheaper models, that everything may just be cemented in, in which case things get quite a bit more difficult.

One other thing - you might take some shots of a clear sky at something like f/22 with the CPL on and see if you can even detect the hair in the resulting photo. Chances are extremely high that you can't. So, it's almost certain that you don't really need to do this - that hair bothers you a whole lot more than it's likely to bother the capabilities of your filter/lens/camera.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the quarter wave plate (the rear layer) must be at a 45° angle to the direction of the front polarizer for it to work properly. It would probably be wise to make some (eraseible) reference marks on each side before disassembling.

Comment: @MichaelC don't mind me if I misunderstood, but it's a rotating CPL so would you need to?

Comment: @timvrhn Yes. The second plate, which is a quarter-wave retarder, needs to be at a 45° to the actual linear polarizer to get the benefit of a circular polarizer (instead of a plain old linear polarizer). Both have to be rotated in unison so that the 45° angle is preserved.

Comment: Yes, but seeing as how it's a rotating CPL, why bother making marks before disassembling? You just turn it as it's reassembled

Comment: @timvrhn Because you can't just look at a polarizing filter like the first plate or a quarter wave retarder plate like the second and determine their direction of polarity or retardation. When you disassemble it, the two pieces that are held in the same orientation to each other *all of the time* when the filter is assembled will no longer be held together. When the filter is rotated during normal usage, the orientation of the two filter layers *does not change*. **Only the orientation between the entire filter assembly and the the threaded ring holding the filter to the lens changes.**

Comment: The difference in the effect of a polarizer as it is rotated has to do with the angle between the filter and the direction of the light in the scene. You'll get the same effect with or without the quarter wave plate behind the polarizing layer. What you *don't* get without the quarter wave retarder plate is the polarized light allowed through the first layer being repolarized in a circular way so that it does not disable AF and metering in modern cameras. I think you might be confusing the two different functions.

Comment: For the light allowed through the front polarization layer to be "circularly polarised" so that AF and metering work, the second layer **must** be oriented at the same 45° angle to the direction of the linear polarization of the first filter.

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense @MichaelC, I was confused at the functionality of that turning ring. Cheers!